# Getting "An infinite type was inferred for an expression" for query'/request from Halogen

Tags: purescript, purescript-halogen

In my component:

```
data Query a = SetImageUrl Int String a
```

Main (app) component:

```
  eval :: Query ~> H.ParentDSL State Query ChildQuery ChildSlot Void m
  eval = case _ of
    HandleItemChange groupId (LIS.ActiveChanged selected) next -> do
      let apReq = AP.SetImageUrl groupId (imageUrl selected)
      _ <- H.query' CP.cp2 AvatarPictureSlot (H.request apReq)
      pure next
```

Compiler says:

```
[1/1 InfiniteType] src/App.purs:85:57

  85        _ <- H.query' CP.cp2 AvatarPictureSlot (H.request apReq)
                                                              ^^^^^

  An infinite type was inferred for an expression:

    t0 -> t0

  while trying to match type t0 -> t0
    with type t0
  while checking that expression apReq
    has type (t0 -> t0) -> t1 t0
  in value declaration app

  where t0 is an unknown type
        t1 is an unknown type
```

I think slots and child paths are alright, because `render` function compiles and works correctly.

**How to fix this error?** I checked several times against guide, but I simply don't see any difference and the compiler message is super unhelpful (for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from github:

```
  _ <- H.query' CP.cp2 AvatarPictureSlot (H.action apReq)
```

For queries not returning anything one should use `H.action` not `H.request`.